# Rounding to nearest five

Tags: objective-c, floating-point, integer, rounding

So I'm working on a custom slider and I'm quite close to getting this, but can't seem to figure out how to get this to round to the nearest 5. Could someone help me sort this out?

```
int distance = progress;
roundedValue = roundf(distance / 5.0f) * 5.0f;
int distanceInt = (int) roundedValue;
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", distanceInt];
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: nearest five means? 84 -> 85
88 -> 90
92 -> 90
96 -> 95 ????

Comment: Correct that's what I'm attempting to do. Did you have anything in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried this way, nothing more than you, and it is giving me what you want.

```
-(NSString *)test:(NSInteger)progress{
    NSInteger distance = progress;
    float roundedValue = roundf(distance / 5.0f) * 5.0f;
    int distanceInt = (int) roundedValue;
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", distanceInt];

}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification{

    for (NSInteger i=0; i<100; i+=4) {
        NSLog(@"%ld -> %@",i, [self test:i]);
    }

}
```

Output:

> ```
> 0 -> 0
> 4 -> 5
> 8 -> 10
> 12 -> 10
> 16 -> 15
> 20 -> 20
> 24 -> 25
> 28 -> 30
> 32 -> 30
> 36 -> 35
> 40 -> 40
> 44 -> 45
> 48 -> 50
> etc
> ```

Comment: eww, expecting a float shoved into an int to give you consistent and proper results does not make for a good algorithm.

Comment: Thanks Anoop! After looking more carefully at the slider the scale was so fine that when a user slid their finger over the slider to change it, it was incrementing by 5, 10 and sometimes 15. The problem being that it was such a small screen and hard to be precise. I changed the incrementation to 25 and it's now much easier to hit the target on the iPhone, when a user runs their finger over the slider.

Answer (score 0):

Old question by now, came across in passing and CodaFi's remark rang true. For any other passers by, consider:

```
int distanceInt = (distance / 5) * 5; // largest multiple of 5 <= distance
if ( (distance - distanceInt) >= 3 )
   distanceInt += 1; // if remainder >= 3 round up
```

No floating point required.